# jQuery Lightbox Not working in IE7/6

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

We are using a heavily modded version of [the jquery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) to create a lightbox with a gallery on the side. However, when I do

```
$('.popup').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
```

IE 7/6 gives me an error on that line. This works on every other browser. Now of course, being IE 7 and 6, theres no actual error description, so I'm not really sure what to do.

For reference, the `popup` class is on a set of links to images that all get opened as a gallery.

I am looking for a better way to debug this problem, or if anyone knows if there is a certain incompatibility with the jquery lightbox that I am using and IE 7/6.

If you know how to solve it, that is perfect too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightbox doesnt have any issues i know of so if anything its probably your modifications, but i would be willing to bet its just a trailing comma in a hash somewhere, like:

```
{
  propertyOne: 'value',
  propertyTwo: 'value', // this comma should not be here 
}
```